# Let's clean up the post notices!

Tags: discussion, post-notice

As you know, we annotate posts with "citation-needed" notices when they don't reference any sources.

What you may not know, is that there is a list of such posts [available here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed), visible to everyone!

**What do we need to do with it? Simple: let us review the notices!**

## General guidelines

1. If a post has a notice, but also has sources in it, it's probably been fixed

   *Please review the sources and vote appropriately. If you feel that the post has enough support, flag it for mod attention with the comment `remove notice`*
2. If a post has a notice and no sources, and the post has not been touched after May 1st 2012 it's probably been abandoned

   *Please consider if you can add sources yourselves and/or vote appropriately. If you do not put in sources, flag the post for mod attention as `abandoned`. [If you can](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user), you may want to vote to delete the most egregious bad examples at this point.*
3. If the post has been touched since May 1st 2012, vote on it as you deem appropriate, but do not flag for mod attention.

This should allow us to remove some of the notices, give credit where credit is due and do a general clean up of answer that need some love and attention.

Comment: FYI *just* the word "abandoned" is too short to use as a flag message. I had to use "abandoned." :)

Comment: I have recently proposed a meta question, in case you didn't notice, in order to help moderators by alerting them about improved answers after post notices: [Alert a moderator when an answer is improved after a post notice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135786/176533)

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing a bit of flagging but just want to be sure that what I'm doing is appropriate. My "moderator attention" notes are generally:

- remove notice - (explanation of how I've improved the answer or statement that it does in fact have references)
- delete answer - (explanation that this is a very, very low quality answer, has no references and the answerer has made little / no effort to improve it in many months). I say this instead of "abandoned" to hopefully make a distinction between "this answer is salvageable and needs improvement" and "this is utter garbage that is beyond hope".

I don't have the rep to vote to delete (20K?), so I'm hoping that it's okay to flag bad posts in this manner.